# Dependency injection from Storyboard iOS13

Tags: swift

I want to launch the storyboard ViewController with a dependency - but my solution always calls `required init?(coder: NSCoder)`

So `SceneDelegate`

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
         self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController", creator: { coder in
            return ViewController(coder: coder, user: "user")
        }) 
        
         let rootNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
         self.window?.rootViewController = rootNC
         self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

within the view controller we have

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var user: String!

    init?(coder: NSCoder, user: String) {
        self.user = user
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print (selectedUser)
    }


}
```

which works - but users could call the `required init` directly.

Now the canonical way seems to be to put a fatal error in the `required init?`, for example

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError()
}
```

however this is always called.

Why is the required init always called - how can I stop that happening?

Answer (score 1):

The `required init?(coder: NSCoder)` method is getting called due to the fact that the `Main` storyboard is set as the initial loading screen of App. You'll have to remove this by going to the info.plist and removing it value `Main` from 2 places.

1. Main storyboard file base name.
2. Application Scene Manifest/Scene Configuration/Application Session Role/Item 0/Storyboard Name.

Comment: but: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-storyboards